# LiDAR XYZ Data Cleaning

Tags: qgis, lidar, noise

I have tons of LiDAR Bathymetric XYZ data of 5m resolution.

Data has a lot of noise/spikes which takes ages to clean for a small area. I have tried using Fledermaus for 3D cleaning the data. Is there any software available to automatically clean and visualize the data, using Standard Deviation?

Comment: You can post this question on software-recommendation site.

Comment: Have you tried [lidR](https://github.com/Jean-Romain/lidR)? I have no idea if your data is compatible with it though, or if the filters you are looking for exists

Comment: Are you sure it is LiDAR data? 5 m resolution does not have a meaning for point clouds.

Comment: GlobalMapper with the LiDAR module has QA/QC and stats tools https://www.bluemarblegeo.com/products/global-mapper-lidar.php

Comment: CloudCompare has noise filters, too. See https://www.cloudcompare.org/doc/wiki/index.php?title=Noise_filter